# Using XPathResult

Tags: xpath

I'm finding little documentation on XPathResult on the mozilla developper site. All functions listed redirect to the main page, so they're probably not documented yet.

```
var myFind;
myFind = document.evaluate(
    '/html/body/table[1]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
```

I'm looking for a way to alert the HTML tree that is under the path given.

Using `alert(myFind);` doesn't work, it just gives "XPathResult".
There's just a tbody and a bunch of tr elements beneath it, and I'd like to see them all in an alert as 1 string.

What function can myFind use to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var myFind;
myFind = document.evaluate(
    '/html/body/table[1]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null);

var node = myFind.singleNodeValue;
```

I'm using `FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE` because you're only looking for a single table.  `singleNodeValue` lets you extract the node.

Now node is a regular HTML DOM [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node).  You can serialize it the same way as any other node, e.g. with [serializeToString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML):

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node)
```

You may find [Using XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XPath) and [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPathResult) helpful.