# How do I retrieve the value of a specific XML node by path?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

**I am looking for a Javascript solution to this problem:**

I have an XML document which is loaded by way of a typical AJAX method:

`var xml = http.responseXML;`

Consider the following example xml snippet:

```
<main>
    <primary>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
     </primary>
     <secondary>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
     </secondary>
 </main>
```

I would like to get the value of a node by specifying the path as follows:

```
var second_enabled = getNodeValueByPath('main/secondary/enabled', xml);
```

I cannot find any concise way of doing something like this. I seem to be forced to iterate through node collections after using `getElementsByTagName` and the like.

How would I construct the method `getNodeValueByPath` or is there some construct in Javascript that allows for this?

I am not well versed in Javascript.

**EDIT:** Here is an example that shows my attempt at using XPath and how it is failing:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<main xmlns="example.com">
  <primary>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </primary>
  <secondary>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </secondary>
</main>
```

**JavaScript:** (these are the relevant functions only)

```
function useHttpResponse()
{
    if (http.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(http.status == 200)
        {
            var xml = http.responseXML;
            var evalue = getXMLValueByPath('/main/secondary/enabled', xml);
            alert(evalue);
        }
    }
}

function getXMLValueByPath(nodepath, xml)
{
    var result = xml.evaluate(nodepath, xml, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
    return result;
}
```

I am using the above JavaScript without any additional libraries. I am using Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13 which uses the document.evaluate method to select nodes (according to [this information from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp)). *This application is for internal use and does not have to work on multiple browsers.*

Given these examples, the alert dialog will appear, but contain no text. If I remove the string `xmlns="example.com"` from the XML document, the alert dialog appears with the text "false" as desired.

Debugging using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) shows that `resultNode` is an empty string as long as the namespace is declared.

Comment: Based on answers so far, also looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739588/using-xpathresult

Comment: Note that the issue is affected by XML namespaces. In the sample XML of my question, the namespace declaration is not present. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505103/how-to-remove-xml-namespaces-using-javascript) for related information.

Comment: Check my answer for an XPath 1.0 explanation plus an example for your specific XPath engine.

Comment: If you don't mind "CSS selectors" instead of XPath, you may be able to get away with "just" JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is FAQ: In XPath 1.0, a QName test without prefix selects elements under the null (or empty) namespace URI. So you need to register a prefix to the default namespace URI from your input source (`example.com`).

How do you do that with DOM 3 XPath API?

From http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate

> `evaluate`
>   Evaluates an XPath
>   expression string and returns a result
>   of the specified type if possible.
>   **Parameters**
>   [...]
>   `resolver` **of type** `XPathNSResolver`
>   The resolver permits translation of all
>   prefixes, including the `xml`
>   namespace prefix, within the XPath
>   expression into appropriate namespace
>   URIs. If this is specified as `null`,
>   any namespace prefix within the
>   expression will result in
>   `DOMException` being thrown with the
>   code `NAMESPACE_ERR`.

And from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate

> ```
> var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
>  xpathExpression, 
>  contextNode, 
>  namespaceResolver, 
>  resultType, 
>  result);
> ```
>
> - `namespaceResolver` is a function that will be passed any namespace prefixes and should return a string representing the namespace URI 
>     associated with that prefix. It will 
>     be used to resolve prefixes within 
>     the XPath itself, so that they can be 
>     matched with the document. `null` is 
>     common for HTML documents or when no 
>     namespace prefixes are used.

Following this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript), you can use [`document.createNSResolver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createNSResolver) or a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver) like:

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {   
  return prefix == 'ex' ? 'example.com' : null;   
}  

function useHttpResponse()
{
  if (http.readyState == 4)
  {
     if (http.status == 200)
     {
        var xml = http.responseXML;
        var evalue = xml.evaluate('string(/ex:main/ex:secondary/ex:enabled)',
                                  xml,
                                  nsResolver,
                                  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
                                  null);
        alert(evalue.stringValue);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Alejandro, this is *exactly* what I was needing all along. Thank you for putting the puzzle together.

Comment: @JYelton: You are wellcome. I'm glad it could help you. About last `useHttpResponse()` JavaScript function: I've just used your example, but remember that in real scenario you will have to iterate over a node set result from `evaluate()` JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with the same thing, I tried a few XPath JS libraries, here's one: http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/, but having said that, I couldn't get stuff working so I'll be watching this question avidly :)

Also, at SO: [Cross-browser XPath implementation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183369/cross-browser-xpath-implementation-in-javascript)

Comment: I hope I didn't put you off that 1st link, I gave up because I only had 45 mins to implement it, so I moved on to other things intending fully to come back later and leverage that library.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xpathtosearchfor = '//div';
var result = new XPathEvaluator().evaluate(xpathtosearchfor,
    document.documentElement, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

In firefox at least

Comment: The Xpath lib in my answer normalises Xpath 1.0 - touting IE/Mozilla consistency. IE doesn't 'do' evaluate(), but does do selectNodes().

Comment: This returns an `XPathResult` object rather than a value. Using the `XPathResult` property `.stringValue` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Upon more investigating, this works when I remove the namespace declaration from the XML. I haven't yet figured out how to get the namespace specified in the XPath; I'd prefer to just remove the namespace entirely from the XML prior to parsing.

Comment: Can you please update your question to say which XPath library you are using, show the code, show the actual XML (you posted XML has no namespace declarations), and show what the result is when you do not remove the namespaces.

Comment: @John Saunders: Added code and error information as requested.

Answer (score -2):

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("d:\\one.xml");
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"//main/secondary/enabled");
string result = ((XmlElement)xNode).FirstChild.Value;
```

Comment: using JavaScript, not C#, I guess

Comment: -1: Getting a specific node value by path is very easy in C# (using `SelectSingleNode` and that nodes' `InnerText` property (for strings)). My question is for Javascript, which is a good deal more frustrating.