# Get Element in xml by using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have xml as follows:

```
<a>
  <a>
    <d>0</d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <d>99</d>
  </a>
</a>
```

This is my code javascript.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var d = a[1].getElementsByTagName("d")[0].firstChild.data;
document.write("d = " + d);
```

The result is `d = 0` but my expected result is `d = 99`.

Could you help me please?

I want to input only index 1 `(a[1])` i do not want to input index 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495569/how-do-i-retrieve-the-value-of-a-specific-xml-node-by-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the value of a specific XML node by path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495569/how-do-i-retrieve-the-value-of-a-specific-xml-node-by-path)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMParser function to create a xmlDoc and than read from it required value. The problem was in your element selector.

```
var text = "<a> <a> <d>0</d></a><a><d>99</d></a></a>"
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
var dNode = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('a a:last-child d')[0];
var dNodeValue = dNode.innerHTML;

console.log(dNodeValue);
// 99
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are looking for `a[2]`:

```
<a> <-- a[0]
  <a>  <-- a[1]
    <d>0</d>
  </a>
  <a>  <-- a[2]
    <d>99</d>
  </a>
</a>
```

Here is the update:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var d = a[2].getElementsByTagName("d")[0].firstChild.data;
          ^---- this is what changed
document.write("d = " + d);
```